# Is there a linker flag in gcc to stamp a unique version in the elf library?

Tags: c

I have generated an elf shared library. I want to stamp a version (like 1.2.2) in the elf header. Can I do it using the linker flags of gcc? If not, is there any other way to stamp the version?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if there is any option to [`ld`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ld) that fits your need, then pass it with the GCC option [`-Wl`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#index-Wl-1030).

Comment: I already tried to do so, but couldnt find one.

The ld man page gives the following option:
       --major-image-version value
           Sets the major number of the "image version".  Defaults to 1.  [This option is specific to the i386 PE targeted port of the linker]

       --major-os-version value
           Sets the major number of the "os version".  Defaults to 4.  [This option is specific to the i386 PE targeted port of the linker]

But, when I try to use it using the -Wl option, it gives me an error.

Answer (score 0):

For shared objects you can use `-Wl,-soname,libmyname.so.1.2.3`.

Comment: I thought of this idea. But, since we have many clients, I was trying to avoid the library name. I know that the symbolic link from libmyname.so to libmyname.so.1.2.3 should work, but since the library is loaded on demand by many clients, I wasn't sure if the sym-link would cause any issues.

Comment: Also, by using -soname, shouldnt all my clients set the DT_SONAME to 1.2.3 in their binaries to load my new library? Ideally, we would not want clients to make any changes, yet have some version information in our library so that by we can track the version information if we jsut get the library.